# Does a double integral calculate an area or a volume?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This takes a little explanation.  I realize that double integrals can be used to calculate both an area or a volume but should I assume that in the case of calculating the area I am really calculating the volume and multiplying it by a height of 1 which just gives you the area?

Or are they really two different techniques that depend solely on the context of the assigned problem ?

Comment: Does it matter?  It sounds like you have a confident understanding of the issues either way.

Comment: You could ask the same question for a single integral: if $f$ is nonnegative, $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \iint_{a<x<b,0<y<f(x)} 1 \, dx \, dy $.

Comment: Funny! I asked the very same thing three years ago. You might be interested in reading some of the answers I received back then
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649034/finding-volumes-when-to-use-double-integrals-and-triple-integrals

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, integration is defined as a suitable limit of a sum. Depending on what we are adding in the sum this limit can be different things.

Also for a single integral of a function $y=f(x)$ we can have an area as in
$$
A=\int_a^b f(x)dx
$$
or arc length as in
$$
L=\int_a^b \sqrt{1+{f'(x)}^2}dx
$$

Comment: Let us say that we are calculating the volume under a given surface , $z=f(x,y)$ .I have read in text books that the volume under this surface is $\iint f(x,y) \, dx \, dy$. However , i am eager to know how this limit comes using the definition of an integration being a limit of a sum. Can you demonstrate by taking a small cube and finding its volume and then summing over these small volumes by taking the limit . Sorry for bothering.

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances, the triple integral evaluates Volume as it spans three dimensions and double integral evaluates area as it spans two dimensions.  A case in point is something like this what @chappers had already indicated.

For example, the volume of a solid between two planes could be written as

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{r}\int_{z_{bottom}}^{z_{top}} dV = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{r}\int_{z_{bottom}}^{z_{top}} rdzdrd\theta = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{r}\left[z_{top} - z_{bottom}\right]rdrd\theta$

The last one is a double integral but the first two are triple integral all measuring the volume.